# Detect if browser is vbscript capable?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript

I was hoping i could use modernizer (or similar) to determine if a browser was capable of running vbscript.  It doesn't look like i can.

Recently IE11 has modified the user-agent removing MSIE and replacing with 'Trident'.  This was done to make IE look more like other browsers in compliance with html specs.

I have a number of old sites that require the browser to support vbscript.  I am looking for a way to determine how I can determine if the browser supports vbscript.  A number of these sites use classic asp which makes it more difficult.

Ideas? ty
Right now, I am thinking of using javascript to evaluate the user agent and if it contains msie then we can assume it does support vbscript.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way I was able to do this was as follows (might be a cleaner way, but I don't know VBScript, I just know Modernizr).

```
var supportsVb = (function() {
  var supports = false;
  var vb = document.createElement('script');
  vb.type="text/vbscript";
  try {
    vb.innerText="Err.Raise";
  } catch (e) {
    supports = true;
  }
  return supports
})()
```

The idea being that only vbscript engines will raise an error for that syntax.

It can be used like this:

```
if (supportsVb) {
    // Make a vbscript call
} else {
    // Make a javascript call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Build the page to give then "VBScript is not supported" experience.

Then add VBScript to transform it (adding and removing DOM elements) to the "VBScript is supported" version.

Comment: The issue is we have numerous old applications that we cannot re-write and only want to provide warning or redirect user if vbscript is not supported.